# Why is mouseenter/mouseleave affecting .click event?

Tags: jquery

I'm making a rating system, and I want it so when you click on each word, it gives it full transparency.  Also, when you hover over each word, the ones before it are highlighted as well.

Basically, the only problem I have with this is the fact that the .click(); event isn't working.  It works **ONLY** if you take out all the code above:

```
    // This isn't working:
$("#poor").click(function () {
    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
});

$("#good").click(function () {
    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
});

$("#great").click(function () {
    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
});
```

**jsFiddle Demo** :: http://jsfiddle.net/MatthewKosloski/rjFpn/1/

Comment: It still triggers a mouseleave event after you click it and then hover out of it; you should be setting some sort of flag, maybe a data attribute on the el, after you click it. Then check the attr on mouseleave/mouseenter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now when you are handling the event you are referencing the event as "this".

Change your code to look like this:

```
$("#poor").click(function (event) {
    var el = event.target || event.srcElement;
    $(el).css("opacity", "1");
});
```

EDIT: Turns out I was wrong, the reason is because when you do a mouse leave you are changing the css property of the element, after the person has clicked, if you set a flag for when the user has clicked an element, you can prevent the mouseleave event from firing

Here's the JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/jDjSu/

Comment: What kind of flag?  I'm new to JS, sorry about asking.  I think I know what you mean.. like something = false?

Comment: if you are using that you should have something like this for full browser compatability `var el = event.target || event.srcElement;`

Comment: Thanks, I'll add that in.

Answer (score 2):

The click is properly setting the opacity to 1, but after that your mouseleave is once again setting the opacity to 0.50.

So mouseleave is un-doing your click.